# \smash command in amsmath

Tags: amsmath

The amsmath package redifines the `\smash` command. In the manual we can see that `\smash` can make adjacent radicals more consistent, for example by using

> `\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{y}}+\sqrt{z}`

The output is satisfactory:
[image]

However, now I want to print the following formula such that the radicals are consistent. What should I do?

> `\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{y}}+\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{h}`

The output of the above code is:
[image]

Comment: `\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{y}}+\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{\smash[t]{h}}`. The square bracket after `\smash` takes an optional argument, `b` for smashing the bottom, `t` for smashing the top. Although in your case, I would recommend `\sqrt{x\mathstrut}+\sqrt{y\mathstrut}+\sqrt{z\mathstrut}+\sqrt{h\mathstrut}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting uniform radicals is a bit of a black art…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{h} \\
\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{y}}+\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{h} \\
\sqrt{x\mathstrut}+\sqrt{y\mathstrut}+\sqrt{z\mathstrut}+\sqrt{h\mathstrut} \\
\sqrt{x\vphantom{h}}
  +\sqrt{\smash{y}\vphantom{h}}\vphantom{y}
  +\sqrt{z\vphantom{h}}
  +\sqrt{h\vphantom{h}}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

(1) is out of question; (2) is passable; (3) has too big radicals.

[image]